# MYSQL join a table and get the guest staying between certain dates

Tags: mysql

Here is a the question I was given along with the schema

> List guests with their name and address who have booked a room from “13/01/2016” to “19/01/2016”.
>
> Booking (*hotelNo*, *guestNo*, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
>
> Guest (*guestNo*, guestName, guestAddress)

Please not that the PK and FK in each table are in italic

This is the syntax I have used this is a question on a exam so this is just for practical purposes.

So I have used this and I would like to know if it is the correct way of going about it?

```
SELECT g.guestName, g.guestAddress
FROM Guest g 
    JOIN Booking b ON g.guestNo = b.guestNo
WHERE b.dateFrom DATE(2016-01-13) >=  b.dateTo DATE(2016-01-19)
```

Comment: Check the WHERE clause, Thats not a legal syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause is not syntactically correct. Try

```
SELECT g.guestName, g.guestAddress
FROM Guest g 
    JOIN Booking b ON g.guestNo = b.guestNo
WHERE DATE(b.dateFrom) >= '2016-01-13'
AND   DATE(b.dateTo) <= '2016-01-19'
```

Comment: @ RiggsFoly: So in the second one you do not have to even uses the dateTo?

Comment: O woops I boobed, ignore that one :)

Comment: So I do not need to even write DATE('2016-01-19')?

Comment: No a date in the correct format as a quoted literal is all you need as long as its in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: if `dateFrom` and `dateTo` are `DATE` datatype, then we can reference the bare columns, it is not necessary to wrap those columns in the `DATE` function.

Comment: Liam, what is the data type of those 2 date columns

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT g.guestName, g.guestAddress
FROM Guest g 
    JOIN Booking b ON g.guestNo = b.guestNo
WHERE b.dateFrom >=DATE('2016-01-13') AND  b.dateTo <=DATE('2016-01-19')
```

Comment: Except you really dont need to do `DATE('2016-01-13')` etc as that is in a valid date format for MySQL

Answer (score 2):

To get bookings where the from date and to date exactly match the two dates given, assuming the `datefrom` and `dateto` columns are `DATE` datatype, we can do something like this:

```
  WHERE b.datefrom = '2016-01-13' 
    AND b.dateto   = '2016-01-19'
```

Note that this will only return reservations for that exact time period, and will exclude guest reservations that start earlier or end later, but may overlap the days in the period.

If we want to find guests that have a reservation that overlaps *any* one or more days in the given period, that's a bit more complicated. (There's answered questions on StackOverflow about identifying overlaps.) The condition will vary depending on whether we want to exclude or include the start date and/or end date, but in general, a pattern something like this to get reservations that overlap some *part* of the time period:

```
  WHERE b.datefrom <= '2016-01-19'
    AND b.dateto   >= '2016-01-13'
```

would return e.g. reservation from `'2016-01-11'` to `'2016-01-15'`

To get reservations that overlap that *entire* range of dates, where the reservation includes all of the dates between the 13th and 19th, but possibly other dates earlier or later, then something like:

```
  WHERE b.datefrom <= '2016-01-13'
    AND b.dateto   >= '2016-01-19'
```

would return e.g. reservation from `'2016-01-11'` to `'2016-01-19'`

To get reservations that are for days that are entirely within the data range, but do not include any days before or after

```
  WHERE b.datefrom >= '2016-01-13'
    AND b.dateto   <= '2016-01-19'
```

would return e.g. reservation from `'2016-01-14'` to `'2016-01-15'`

Comment: So I do not need to even write DATE('2016-01-19')?

Comment: In MySQL, It is valid to write `DATE('2016-01-19')` , but no, its not *required* to wrap a date literal in the DATE function, since the datatype conversion is implicit. If the literal includes a time portion, and we want to truncate that, we could write `DATE('2016-01-19 09:30:00')` to have just the date part returned, as if we had written `'2016-01-19 00:00:00'`.